# Angular 9 template interpolation removing backslashes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template, angular-dom-sanitizer

I need to render a string on the page with double backslash "\\" but Angular removes one from the temaplte, treating it like a regular expression.

An example of the issue is here:
https://codepen.io/bental/pen/xxZdYZv

I have also tried escaping with and without `DomSanitizer` but can't seem to make it work.

I don't want to manipulate the data as it's coming from the backend and can't account for every possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need IE/Opera support, you can use `String.raw` (note that you need to use backticks instead of double quotes for it to work as intended)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(String.raw`Double backslashes are being removed -> \\`);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, weird it's not a function - I'll go with this

Comment: @BenTaliadoros You can look at the template strings reference for more info about backticks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2):

put `\\\\` every `\\` represents one `\`

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("Double backslashes are being removed -> \\\\")
```

Comment: I get the data from the backend - I'll update the post to make this clear. I don't really want to manipulate the string for each instance of this - is it just backslashes?